# What is this "should?"

Tags: grammar

There are two things that men **should** never weary of, goodness and humility; we get none too much of them in this rough world among cold, proud people.

Is this the same as "It should be sunny tomorrow?"

[Source](http://classiclit.about.com/library/bl-etexts/rlstevenson/bl-rlst-kid-16.htm)

Comment: http://www.englishpage.com/modals/should.html

Answer (score 3):

*Should* is a **modal auxiliary verb**, which is a very special category of auxiliary verb in English.

> *can, could, shall, should, may,  might, will, would, must,* and sometimes *need* and *dare*

Modals have [a number](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/aue/modals.html) of [strange characteristics](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/Modality.pdf)
One of these is that they are  systematically ambiguous.
All English modal auxiliaries have at least two kinds of meaning:

1. a deductive or inductive logical possibility or necessity, called the ***Epistemic*** meaning.
2. a moral permission or necessity, originating from natural or social forces, called ***Deontic***.

The epistemic sense of *should* is something like "likely by induction", not all that different from the "likely by deduction" of epistemic *must*. Both are used to announce hypotheses derived from theory or experience.

- *It should be sunny tomorrow.*
- *He should be home by now.*
- *He must be home by now.*
- *This should be the store he mentioned.*
- *This must be the store he mentioned.*

The deontic sense of *should* is something like "mild obligation", contrasting with the "strong obligation" of deontic *must*. It's usually a matter of reminder and nagging, rather than order and obligation.

- *Men should never weary of goodness and humility.*
- *You really should get your gutters cleaned before the snow starts.*
- *I know I should do it, but I just never have time.*
- *You must have your gutters cleaned or pay a fine.*

**Reminder**: ***All*** modals have two senses, not just *should*. They're easy to tell apart once you learn.

Answer (score 2):

The first statement is more like a moral standpoint, in the sense what,in an ideal state, should or should not happen.Something like a commandment.

*One should not steal.*

The second statement is more like an educated guess:

It should be sunny tomorrow.

would read something like:

**Given the weather conditions today, I assume it would be sunny tomorrow.*

*(Given my performance), I should clear the interview*.*

Comment: But the first one doesn't make it make sense. This is not about obligations if you have read the entire text.

Comment: After your comment, I did go back and read the context.I maintain it is a moral standpoint or an ideal truth, in the protagonist's viewpoint.The slight irreverential tone, does not change the core meaning.

Answer (score 1):

The main purpose of *should* is to express obligation. That is what it is doing in the first sentence. A secondary purpose is to express deduction. That is what it is doing in the second sentence.

Answer (score 0):

Both *should never weary* and *should be sunny* can be read as predictions of future events, based on past observation of men and weather.

There is a subtle difference *why* each *should* play out as predicted.

I read the author as arguing there is *value* in men not wearying, perhaps for their own good.  The author is hopeful or even commanding for a specific future event.  This is distinct from men being *likely* to not worry, as the weather is *likely* to be sunny in the future, based on evidence.